# Comparing int values of two data files in C

Tags: c, file, csv

I am given 3 files of integers representing three different readings of temperatures for different days. I need to compare the three integers each day to find out if theres a faulty reading if one does not match the other two. I keep getting an error that says

```
invalid operands to binary expression ('FILE'
      (aka 'struct __sFILE') and 'FILE'
 if(*(data1+i)==*(data2+i) && data3[i]!=data1[i])
```

my Code is

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  FILE *data1, *data2, *data3;

  data1=fopen(argv[2], "r");
  data2=fopen(argv[3], "r");
  data3=fopen(argv[4], "r");

  int c1=0; int c2=0; int c3=0; int unkown=0;

  for(int i=0; i<argc; i++){
    if(*(data1+i)==*(data2+i) && data3[i]!=data1[i])
      c3++;
    if(data1[i]==data3[i] && data2[i]!=data1[i])
      c2++;
    if(data3[i]==data2[i] && data1[i]!=data2[i])
      c1++;
    if(data1[i]!=data2[i] && data1[i]!=data3[i] && data3[i]!=data2[i])
      unkown++;
  }
  printf("Data1 has %d possible bad values\nData2 has %d possible bad values\nData3 has %d possible bad values\nThere are %d unkown cases\n", c1, c2, c3, unkown);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `dataX` in your code are *file descriptors* and not a data or pointer to data you can dereference. You use the descriptors with other file operations such as `fread`.

Comment: Or `fscanf` if the files are text files. Showing a sample of your files would help us understand the question. There's also the issue that the temperature changes. I wouldn't expect three temperature readings  to match perfectly. I'd expect them to occasionally differ by a degree or two.

Comment: Data1: 72 83 92 84 etc.  Data2: 72 84 91 84 etc. Data3: 72 83 92 81 etc.

Comment: So the first thing to do is write code that opens one file, reads the file and prints the values. You can read the numbers with code like: `int temperature; while (fscanf(data1, "%d", &temperature) == 1) { dosomething() }`

Comment: @CharlieP the question title says "CSV files" which means "comma separated values". Please post the actual input *in the question.*

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, like Eugene suggested, you need first need to read all your files to a character array and then read from that. I wrote a piece of code for an assignment that I am willing to share:

```
void readFile(const char *fileName, char **text, int *filelen)
{
    FILE *f;

    f = fopen(fileName, "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    *filelen = ftell (f);

    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    *text = malloc((*filelen + 1) * sizeof(char));
    if(*text)
    {
        fread(*text, 1, *filelen, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    (*text)[*filelen] = '\0';
}
```

You can then initialize all the variables and do the function call like this (for example):

```
char *fileText;
int filelen;

readFile("filename.txt", &fileText, &filelen);
```

Only, you should make several *fileText* and *filelen* variables when you're working with several files and change *"filename.txt"* to the correct filename(s).

If you only need the data once and want to discard of it after that you don't need to save to a character array first. You can directly use fgetc or fscanf to analyze your data.

Comment: @CharlieP I would not recommend this approach of reading the files into memory (it is almost always unnecessary, needs more memory, prevents using pipes and devices as input, etc), but if you do it, you need to add error checking (which is completely missing here). But rather just read from the files directly instead of this.

Comment: Also, as a stylistic note, multiplying by `sizeof char` is unneccessary, since it is 1 by definition. And the space between function name and `(` when calling is quite unusual.